# Is there a Blackberry Browser emulator?

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I'm developing a mobile site that needs to work in Blackberry browsers. This is not an app; just a website with custom stylesheets. Is there a Blackberry browser emulator available somewhere, or do I need to use one of the simulators, which give you the entire BB system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you have to use the [simulators](https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477) provided by RIM.

Comment: Urg. I was hoping there was something like ies4linux that would let me  see how different mobile browsers render a website. Oh, well.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477
Is where I've downloaded an emulator for the Blackberry Pearl. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I've found a Chrome extension which attempts to emulate all mobile devices:

[Ripple for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc)  ([ripple.tinyhippos.com](http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/))

But, I have found it to be somewhat untrustworthy, testing Blackberry using jQuery mobile wasn't much help unfortunately...

>_<