# JQuery Mobile Blackberry workaround

Tags: c#, blackberry, jquery-mobile, blackberry-simulator

I have been trying to get a working emulator to test this, but I keep getting errors.

I have a mobile app that uses JQuery Mobile. Unfortunately (as far as I know) blackberry (not 6.0) does not support JQuery mobile.

To get around this I am trying to do this method:

1. On pageload of my app check to see if the phone is a black berry
2. If black berry redirect away from jquery mobile page to regular html

**Questions:**

1) Is there a better way to do this? I have all the functionality in my JQuery mobile so a quick workaround that would work with that would be best

2) How can you detect if a phone is a blackberry? I was thinking something along the lines of this (Haven't been able to test it fully because I cannot get my sim working)

```
   //Checks to see if the phone is a blackberry
    if (Request.Headers["User-Agent"] != null && (Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"] == "true" || Request.Browser
        ["BlackBerry"] == "true" || Request.UserAgent.ToUpper().Contains("MIDP") || Request.UserAgent.ToUpper
        ().Contains("CLDC")) || Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("iphone"))
       {
          Response.Redirect("Blackberry/FirstPage.htm");
       }
```

On another note, what is a good simulator for blackberry? I tried the [accepted SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856642/is-there-a-blackberry-browser-emulator) but I cannot get web access and the older versions are throwing many errors.

Thanks

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/ They just announced support for BB5 about 2 weeks ago

Comment: Well that will save me a lot of time. Do you know what version I need? Right now I am using 1.0 A4.1

Comment: I don't.  I just remembered our javascript guys at working talking about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Jquery mobile blog for more information on BlackBerry Support

http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/05/27/jquery-mobile-team-update-week-of-may-23/